# search text value then find a number

Tags: python, python-2.7

i would like to extract the salary and the currency.

```
A= "my name is adam. expected salary usd 5000 USD test test  "
B= "my name is sara. expected salary 8200 MYR test tessksjdkjs "
C= "my name is sara. expected salary IDR 999944 and iam  ksdjfjksdh "
```

how can i search find the expected salary and the currency.

```
The expected results: 

A= salary 5000     CURRENCY   USD
B= salary 8200     CURRENCY   MYR
C= salary 999944   CURRENCY   IDR
```

Comment: have you tried anything? also, where do you want to search, is it a pandas dataframe, a file or what? Your question should have [enough][1] details

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Comment: `import re
for x in A, B, C:
    print(re.findall("\d+", x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is under the assumption that the required data is after text "salary" in the string.

You can use regex to extract the required fields. Then check for integer values, these will be salary and other will be currency.

```
import re
A= "my name is adam. expected salary usd 5000 USD test test  "
B= "my name is sara. expected salary 8200 MYR test tessksjdkjs "
C= "my name is sara. expected salary IDR 999944 and iam  ksdjfjksdh "
for x in A, B, C:
    required_data = re.findall(r'salary ([^/]+)', x)[0].split(' ')[:2]
    if required_data[0].isdigit():
        print 'salary ' + required_data[0] + ' currency ' + required_data[1]

    else:
        print 'salary ' + required_data[1] + ' currency ' + required_data[0]
```

Output

```
salary 5000 currency usd
salary 8200 currency MYR
salary 999944 currency IDR
```

Comment: lets assume that:  i want to input A only based on that. how the code will look like ?